# Creating DLL of C++ code and use for VB.net Application

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have a C++ code, which I was compiling on a Linux system. Now, I am required to use the C++ code in a VB.net. I have looked up several other questions and walkthroughs, however, it just added to the confusion. Some posts suggested usage of Cygwin or MinGW, however, since I am already using Visual Studio(a newbie) to create VB.net, I don't want to indulge in another software.

1. Do I have to make too many changes in the C++ code in order to make a DLL?
2. How do I create it in Visual Studio (ver 2010)?

Here is a sample version of my C++ code.

```
//Cyl.h
class Cyl
{
    double r,l;
    double O[3];

public:
void Set(double r1);
void SetOQ(double r1,double O1[3]);
void Get(double &r1);
void Get(double &r1],double O2[3]);
};

//EE.h
#include "Cyl.h"
class EE
{
protected:
    double r1,r2;
public:
    //Pure Virtual function  Handler 
    virtual int Handler()=0;
    int Set(Cyl &E1,Cyl &E2,double eps1=10e-5);
    int Get(double &r1,double &r2);
};

//EE_derived.h
#include "EE.h"
class EE_derived:public EE
{
public:

    int Handler();

};
```

a. The VB.net code should be able to create objects of the Cyl class.

```
Dim cyl1 As Cyl
```

b. Should be able to call the functions cyl1.Set and able to distinguish function as polymorphism is implemented.

```
Dim a As double =5.001
cyl1.Get(a)
```

c. The VB.net code should be able to pass arrays to the objects created.

d. Create object of the class EE_derived and call the functions Set, Get and Handler

The [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) provides a walkthrough, however, I am not quite sure if this would serve my purpose.

Please advise.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx

Comment: VBA or VB.NET?  Two different animals

Comment: Visual Studio does not use VBA.

Comment: Sorry I am using VB.net.